# Convergence of the series: $\sum_{n=2}^\infty x^{\ln(n)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know that the answer should be $$ x < \frac{1}{e}$$ but cannot figure out how to get it at all.

Thank you for an help!!!

Comment: $x^{\ln n}  = n^{\ln x}$. It is rather a Dirichlet series.

Comment: It would be an interesting problem if we write $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} x^{ \lfloor \ln n \rfloor }$. Then we 'radius of convergence' makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By observing that, for $x>0$, 
$$x^{\ln n}=e^{\ln n \cdot\ln x}=n^{\ln x}$$ one may write
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty x^{\ln n}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{n^{-\ln x}}
$$ then one may recognize a $p$-series: $-\ln x>1$

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(n)=x^{\log(n)}$.  Then, note that

$$\begin{align}
2^nf(2^n)&=2^nx^{n\log(2)}\\\\
&=e^{n\log(2)(1+\log(x))}
\end{align}$$

Then, since the geometric series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty e^{n\log(2)(1+\log(x))}$ converges for $1+\log(x)<0$, [Cauchy's Condensation Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) guarantees that the series of interest converges for $1+\log(x)<0$ or $x<1/e$ as expected!